# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el icono de DatePicker en Angular 5 Material?

Tags: datepicker, angular5, icons

Estoy trabajando con Angular 5, y debo mostrar un DatePicker, pero modificando el icono que viene por defecto por uno personalizado. Según la documentación (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) debería bastar con el siguiente código:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Por desgracia, lo he probado y en ningún momento cambia el icono que viene por defecto. ¿Alguien ha conseguido modificar dicho icono?

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Probaste utilizando `(click)="picker.open()"` en un `<mat-icon>` afuera del `<mat-form-field>`, como muestra la documentación?

Comment: En ese caso, tengo dos iconos. El que he puesto fuera del <mat-form-field> y el original que se incluye dentro del <mat-datepicker-toggle> que intento sustituir.